# How to differentiate two custom struct types in Golang with same data as keys in map?

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

```
type Student struct {
    id int,
    name string,
}

//If I create two structs, 
s := Student{1, "jack"}
t := Student{1, "jack"}

m := make(map[Student]bool)

m[s] = true
m[t] = true
```

1) Will this work?
2) Is there anything similar to Java's hashCode in Golang?

Comment: As you rightfully point out, Java has the `hashCode` function on all classes. However, in Java you also need to provide the correct implementation of that function for your class.

You will need to provide your own index here to map back

Comment: Otherwise, Is there a possibility of two keys with same values?

Comment: A student must have a unique identifier of some sort. I'd assume id to be unique and would personally jut use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two struct values have the same member values, and if all those members are comparable, then those structs are equal. In your example: `s==t` is `true`. Struct value itself is the map key. So in your example, there will be only one element in the map at the end.

More on comparability:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

There is no equivalent of `hashCode` in Go.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Will this work?

Yes, of course. But you map will contain just one entry.

> 2) Is there anything similar to Java's hashCode in Go[...]?

No.